# Unclear initialiser error

Tags: swift

I have this code :

```
public class Foo {    
    init?() {
        do {
            let sd = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("bar")
            let ressourceValues = try sd.resourceValues(forKeys: [.isDirectoryKey])

            if let isDirectory = ressourceValues.isDirectory {
                if isDirectory {
                    self.something = sd
                } else {
                   return nil
                }
            } else {
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: sd.path, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
            }
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }

    public static let `default`: Foo? = Foo()
    var something: URL
}
```

I get this error on the `init?` line:

> Variable 'self.something' used before being initialized

And yet I don't see any place where I am using it in the initialiser.

What's wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: `self.something` is not initialized in the else-block ...

Comment: @MartinR Oh !! Thanks didn't realise there was a path where it was uninitialised

Comment: define as required `var something: URL!`

Comment: @MartinR I see you marked this as duplicate but unfortunately I cannot delete it myself...

Comment: You don't have to. Duplicate questions are not necessarily bad.

Answer (score 1):

Since `something` isn't optional you must initialize it with a non-nil value. Your `init` may succeed without initializing `something`.